# Как вызвать функцию из динамически подгруженного JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Стоит задача подключить коммент сервер именно динамически, а потом вызвать функцию вызова из API сервера.

Как обратиться к функции динамически подгруженного скрипта?

```
// Подключаем CometServerApi
var loadedJSCometServerApi = document.createElement('script');
loadedJSCometServerApi.src = "https://comet-server.com/CometServerApi.js";
loadedJSCometServerApi.type = "text/javascript";
loadedJSCometServerApi.language = "javascript";

//получаем элемент секции head
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 //вставляем новый script в head
head.appendChild(loadedJSCometServerApi);

var user_id = '1';
var user_key = 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b';
// Запускаем CometServer
CometServer().start({
    dev_id:2148, 
    user_id:user_id, 
    user_key:user_key
});
```

Comment: а у вас `CometServer` в скрипте глобальная переменная?

Comment: сам сервер не мной написан это отдельный сервис. Вот нужно его когда только нужно врубать. А если динамически добавляешь скрипт CometServerApi.js, то уже не работает...

Comment: наверное, нужно подождать, пока скрипт загрузится, а потом уже вызывать его методы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы добавили тег скрипт в документ еще не значит, что можно сразу выполнять его код. Нужно дождаться пока браузер его загрузит/распарсит и только потом будут доступны глобальные переменные из этого скрипта

```js
// Подключаем CometServerApi
var loadedJSCometServerApi = document.createElement('script');
loadedJSCometServerApi.src = "https://comet-server.com/CometServerApi.js";
loadedJSCometServerApi.type = "text/javascript";
loadedJSCometServerApi.language = "javascript";

// Нужно дождаться, пока скрипт загрузится
loadedJSCometServerApi.addEventListener('load', () => {
  var user_id = '1';
  var user_key = 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b';
  // Запускаем CometServer
  CometServer().start({
      dev_id:2148, 
      user_id:user_id, 
      user_key:user_key
  });
});


//получаем элемент секции head
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 //вставляем новый script в head
head.appendChild(loadedJSCometServerApi);
```

Comment: Да-да, уже понял, что сразу обращался к скрипту, который еще не был загружен. Спасибо большое! Совсем забыл как это делается!